# How to host a web application in IIS Express programatically?

Tags: c#, iis-express

I have used the C# code from [Sample code for Adding/Deleting a website programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/06/08/iis7-sample-code-for-addingdeleting-a-website-programmatically-c-example/) to add and remove a web application in IIS. I need to perform the same process in IIS Express using C#. I have surfed through the net and no sample found for this. How to achieve this?

Comment: iis express is meant for development purpose so limited functionality...there might be no way to do this kind of thing

Comment: What's your final objective? Web Acceptance Testing?

Comment: Yes I need to test bunch of MVC/ASP projects by hosting it to IS Express and launch it in a web browser, then take screenshot.

Comment: Jexus Manager is the largest sample project in this area, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager